# Windows and Hints in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi

This morning I finally made my mind and decided to ask you for help. Problem is that in my Delphi application no hints are shown at all...
I have read about THintAction problem, I have read guides/tutorials/manuals, tried to invoke Hint windows ( firing event handlers ) manually, but nothing worked. They just doesnt show.
I have run out of ideas ...

I have tried to: setting parent showhints on components, forms, from event handlers, application activatehint() ...

Is there any other way to do this ( except API calls, of course )?

Comment: Do you use any non-standard libraries? I had the same issue once and it turned out to be a 3rd-party component hijacking the hint management.

Comment: Hmmm, might be, but It requieres some research. I will think of it! Thanks for tip...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, what version of Delphi do you use?

Second, I recommend you try creating a simple application from scratch, with just one form and say a tool-button (or any other control that can show hints), with ShowHints activated, and see if it shows. If on such a very simple app you'll get no hints, I would recommend reinstalling Delphi, maybe something in your installation is screwed up...

Comment: Nop, as I have tried before - any property either from runetime and designtime doesnt invoke hint window....
Also - I had this problem before and reinstallation helped, but I really want to avoid it....

Comment: If at the simplest level you can't show hints, I would guess something is really screwed up with your installation or environment.

Comment: Crap. Mh, ok, got to reinstall ... it seems like that the solution would be pretty hardcoded and unreliable, :(

Comment: I gave up - that is the reason. The solution is to interfer with OS API directly, but I dont have much knowledge about Hints. Also - there is few WinAPI-based solutions in web, but it would make my app way to big so I decided to add Hints when I will have more time to focus on GUI than I have now ... or even never implement. In the basis it is pretty simple - I could create StringList and load necessary Hont by Index / Tag / Label / Sender ... whatever, but it just way to lame if there is special property in object brwser, even if there is some bug in IDE ...

Answer (score 3):

I bet you're on XP and your installation is rather old.

A friend of mine had this exact problem in his machine. No VCL hints were showing up in his machine. That includes the apps he built, the Delphi IDE he used (7 afaicr) and any other Delphi built app he had on his machine. So we had concluded by blaming his WinXP instance which has been on the run for the last 2 years with a lot of garbage in it (most likely it was some app he installed sometime that was hooking messages at some point causing this weird behaviour). It might be your case as well.

ps. Another interesting point - the hints were showing up if you set Application.HintPause to a low value like 100-200. You may want to try that as well.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Finally! Also I would like to point that it might bee mesage hook/intercept with half second delay or a bit less than second :) The thing i might notice is that sometimes my desktop refreshed nonstop with about second interval when I used SE PC Suite 5.0 with my phone while writing code. Ii is possible that some service simply uses some specific messages which causes hint windows to be "owerdrawn" or notification module is locked by the service .... I am starting to think That we should make some bug report / feedback about this ...

Comment: Worked also for me! My app was running on many machines, but only one didn't show the hint. Setting Application.HintPause to "100" fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding Application.ShowHint to your project file?

The project file would then look something like this

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.ShowHint := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TfrmMain, frmMain);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: No need to get frustrated. If all you mention is application, there is no way of knowing you have tried what I suggested.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not meant it as frustration. Just this hint bug starting to p**s me off a bit....

Comment: No offense taken, trust me, I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this problem on Delphi-5, "run-time application won't display hints on mouse-hover".
It works fine on my other applications.

I've traced it to the following:
Project|Options|Compiler|Debugging|Use Debug DCUs
This was checked, unchecking and re-compiling enables my hints.

Answer (score 1):

I also encounter my PC( win10 ) can't show my ap's (made by Delphi 7) hint.
work again after I put following line in .dpr file :
100 is magic number, 500 or 1000 not working.

```
begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.ShowHint := True;
  Application.HintPause:=100;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

- Check if you or another component/unit has set a custom hint class. If so, find that component/unit and remove it.
- Compile your application with Debug DCUs and put breakpoints at the appropriate places in Forms.pas. Then single-step through the code and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - As I Recently Upgraded to 2010 version ( 14.x ), I finally was sure that this Hint problem is Bug in the IDE.

Only solutions is:
- change the HintPause property 
- try to reinstall IDE